# rxjs observer pagination pattern that doesn't use .expand()?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have some existing code that more or less does,

```
this.service.foo(url, qry)
  .expand(obj => (obj.next ? this.service.foo(obj.next, qry) : Observable.empty())
  .map(...)
  .reduce(...)
  .subscribe(response => {
      var items = process(response);
      dosomething(items).subscribe(...);
  }
```

This seems like the standard `expand()` pattern for paginated APIs.  It works first by accumulating all the paginated results and then passing them on to `dosomething()`.

What if I wanted to `dosomething()` as each paged response comes in, in an interleaved manner rather than serial/batch?  Is there a pattern for this?

My fallback is to make the `response` a function that calls `this.service.foo` with the "next" url if it isn't `null`.

Comment: It's not `expand` that accumulates the pages, it's `reduce`. `expand` will emit pages as it receives them. See https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-expand-a5f8b41a3602

Comment: This seems obvious in hindsight!  Thanks!

Comment: The blog post link in the above comment is dead. The canonical link is: https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-expand/